# is it sound practice to normalise & sum numerical variables to create a single metric for a prediction model? e.g's provided

Tags: regression, dataset, data, correlation, aggregation

Does this question aim to understand if this is sound practice? if not, I would appreciate a suggestion.

The goal is to use this metric:

1. regression
2. classification
3. as a metric

| profile_views | emails_clicked | new_metric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.032 | 0.232 | 0.264 |

Comment: welcome, to the Datascience.stackexchange.com. Normalization does not seem to be a healthy practice. However, an answer may be given by an expert, if you clarify your problem in detail.